# How to remove Appearance of tabs on froms by jQuery-Steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with jQuery-Steps library

http://www.jquery-steps.com/

I would like to change in Appearance Setting "**headerTag**" which shows tabs on top of forms.

"**headerTag**" is by default "**H1**"

here is document https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings

js code i used

```
$("#wizard-1").steps({
            headerTag: "h1",
            bodyTag: "fieldset",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            autoFocus: true
        });
```

HTML

```
 <h1 class="noDisplay">Profile</h1>
        <fieldset>my code</fieldset>
```

I want to remove tabs which appears by headerTag.
Is there any option headerTag:none?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

jQuery

```
$('ul[role="tablist"]').hide();
```

Or CSS

```
ul[role="tablist"] {
    display: none;
}
```